# Show a function is integrable on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(p/q)=1/q$ if fraction $p/q$ is in lowest terms and $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$ and when $x=0$. Show it is integrable on $[0,1]$.

My idea: Construct a partition such that $U(p,f)-L(p,f) < \epsilon$. The lower sum should be 0. It suffice to show $U(p,f)< \epsilon$. Consider a interval $[p/q-\delta, p/q+\delta]$. The length and $sup \ f(x)$ of the interval are known.

And I know the number of such interval is finite. However, I do not know how to construct such interval so I do not know how many interval are there exactly.

---

Edit: As OP, I am the first to vote for close, as well as reopen. The reason for close is that the function is the same as the one in the link. However, the reason for reopen is that the definition of integration is slightly different, and I do not stuck in the same place as the OP in the link. In addition, it seems the answer does not address my question. So, I vote for reopen.

Comment: If the asker is satisfied, I'm satisfied.

Comment: Of course, I'd like to see more answers on the question. However...

Comment: You could offer a bounty. I just offered one on it for 50 points, but usually it takes 200 to get a lot of good additional answers.

Comment: Thank you. I've voted for reopen. As OP, it seems I cannot offer bounty within two days.

Comment: I meant a bounty on the question the others said this is a duplicate of. Though I suppose you can't offer a bounty on that one either, at least not for the next couple of days.

Comment: Check this out. 9.b http://www.eriklewis.com/Math230PDFs/Math%20230b%20HW3.pdf